# Can com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication task be cacheable?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-cache

I'm exploring build scan of my Android project and I've found that task `com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication` is not cacheable due to the reason: `Not cacheable: Task output caching not enabled`.

Is it possible to make this task cacheable, for example by setting some flag in the `gradle.properties` file?

I'm using Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.2